# django template if statement

Tags: django, if-statement, django-templates

I have a table that I'm filling with info from a list with a for loop in a template. I would like to end  the current table and create a new on once a particular value is hit. I've written this which prints all the values in the table but doesn't enter the if statement:

```
 <table class="table">
                {% for  x, y, z in defStats %}
                    <tr class = "info">

                        <td>
                            {{ x }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ y }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ z }}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    {% if x == " " %}
                        <p>HERE</p>
                        </table>
                        <table>
                    {% endif %}




                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

the character I'm looking for is a empty string. I've even attempted an if statement that was guaranteed to evaluate as true and did not have it enter the if statement at all:

```
 <table class="table">
                {% for  x, y, z in defStats %}
                    <tr class = "info">

                        <td>
                            {{ x }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ y }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ z }}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    {% if x == x %}
                        <p>HERE</p>
                        </table>
                        <table>
                    {% endif %}




                {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

in both cases the if statement was never entered at all. I'm not sure what is wrong, thank you.

Comment: In the second case, are you sure the updated template was being used? In the first, the empty string is `''`, not `' '` (which is a single space).

Comment: I couldn't figure out the why behind the approach you wish to take, maybe if we know your destination target, we might have a different approach that might equally help

Comment: It was a template issue, i apologize just got it working

Answer (score -1):

Try to Replace :

```
{% if x == " " %}  
 with
{% if x == None %}
```

Comment: This will not test for the empty string. You test against `None` with `is`, though that is not even relevant here.